# Cannot start a sql script when starting mysql via docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a sql script in my project's db folder that doesn't seem to run.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
volumes:
  my-db:
```

in the db folder there is a setup.sql file containing the instructions :

"Create database X"
and "Use database X"

When I connect via docker exec the database is not present

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks !

Comment: You've written `bd` in the volume mapping rather than `db`. Typo?

Comment: No still not, the database does not seem to be created